# Receiving keystrokes

Tags: c, linux

Is there a way to read user input before TTY drivers encounters a line feed character, or an EOF, but without using `/dev/input/event*` i tried using `write(3)` in a loop, but that needs to wait for the TTY driver to send the data to the process's stdin. Also, if I understood correctly, using `/dev/input/event*` will capture *all* keystrokes. I'm only interested in reading from `stdin` before `EOF` or `\n` is encountered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put `stdin` into non-canonical mode, which you can do if `stdin` is a terminal or pseudo-terminal. See `man tcgetattr` or `man termios` (probably the same manpage). Yes, it is a lot of reading :)

Most likely you have the library function `cfmakeraw`, which is the easiest way to put `stdin` into raw mode. That's available with the GNU C library as long as you define the `_BSD_SOURCE` feature-test macro. `cfmakeraw` will do all the usual settings for raw mode, including turning off echoing, so you will have to echo characters typed to `stdout` yourself. You'll also have to deal with interpreting backspace and arrow characters, and all the other niceties of cooked (line-by-line, or canonical) input.

Also, make sure that you reset the terminal to normal mode *even if your program crashes*. (You'll need to use `atexit` for that.)

For what it's worth, you might find it simpler to use the `ncurses` library.

Comment: OK, I would have mentioned ncurses first. Otherwise, what rici said.

Answer (score 2):

Change the terminal settings to disable line-at-a-time input. Be sure to restore the terminal settings when the program exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CNTL_D 4

static struct termios oldtty;

void kbcleanup(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &oldtty);     /* restore old settings */
}

int kbsetup(void)
{
    tcgetattr(0, &oldtty);
    
    struct termios newtty = oldtty;
    newtty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;  /* disable line-at-a-time input */
    newtty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;    /* disable echo */
        
    if (tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &newtty) == 0) {
        atexit(kbcleanup);      /* restore the terminal settings when the program exits */
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    if (!kbsetup()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to set terminal mode\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != CNTL_D) {
        printf(" -- got char 0x%02x" , c);
        if (isprint(c))
            printf(" '%c'\n", c);
        else
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```